# DNS without forwarders

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Just a quick question, 
Will a DNS server be able to resolve queries without having forwarders configured or will it just use root hints to resolve queries in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct in that the DNS server can use root hints instead of forward resolvers.

Comment: Thank you. Was wondering that and didn't have a server to test with.